# AngularJS display div with child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to code a simple AngularJS site where I can display an initially hidden HTML element (and all its children).

I have to following HTML structure (excerpt):

```
<div class="hiddenStuff">
  <h3>Game Over</h3>
  <p class="hiddenMsg">You have won!</p>
  <a href="#" class="buttonStart">Do it again!</a>
</div>
```

In the CSS by default I don't display the div with class "hiddenStuff":

```
.hiddenStuff{
  display: none;
}
```

But now at some point in the AngularJS/JavaScript code I want to display the hidden HTML structure again:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.hiddenStuff')).css({display:'block'});
```

But this only displays the div-element, and not the in the div-element included h3, p and a tags. How can I display everything?

Thank you

Comment: So why don't you set `ng-hide` at the begining then set the value of its parameter to `false` when you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach will be  to use ng-show

```
    <div ng-show="$ctrl.showDiv" class="hiddenStuff">
    <h3>Game Over</h3>
  <p class="hiddenMsg">You have won!</p>
  <a href="#" class="buttonStart">Do it again!</a>
</div>
```

and then in your controller you can declare the variable showDiv to false by default and change the value of showDiv to true when you want to show the div

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow